# How can edit and manage "select_tag options_from_collection_for_select" in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm newbie in Rails and please can some help understand something. I found some code in old project, that i should manage and edit some bugs. Rails version is 3.2, and ruby 1.9.3

Code:

```
.select-style
  = select_tag "passion", options_from_collection_for_select(@passions, "id", "name")
.select-style
  = select_tag "destination", options_from_collection_for_select(@destinations, "id", "name")
```

If I understand right all the collections is in db/data some yml files.
How can edit and manage "select_tag options_from_collection_for_select" in Ruby on Rails application?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select WHat do you mean by `edit and manage it` - do you want to add/remove extra options?

Comment: I googled it but I can't understand how I can add to destination country? I found some country_select gem, but I don't know to do that work together...

Comment: `@passions` and `@destinations` objects are responsible for this as they hold collections of data which is to be used to populate selects. They are populated in your controller by, most likely, querying the database. It is impossible to tell more without seeing your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google it, as specified on this link: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select it will iterate over @passions and call *id* for value and *name* for display of the  tag